# Can review changes in Acrobat Reader (Pro, or not) be 'applied' to a PDF?

Tags: pdf, collaboration, review

As part of an enhancement to my workplace processes, we're trying to streamline review of various documents.

Yeah, there's way better alternatives to what I'm about to suggest, but the reality is that I have no time allocated to investigate things like DAV, repo setups and such.

What I do have time allocated for is improving workflow around tools we already use. So I tried to work through the Adobe PDF collaborative review cycle.

I have to say it was pretty amazing, from the notify toolbar icon to doc merging, to user access control. They offer it all, EXCEPT the ability to actually apply review changes to a PDF!?!

To clarify, after sending a PDF through the collab review cycle (involving a bunch for external editors and internal staff) the end result was a PDF full of rich feedback - but I can see no way to finalised and apply those 'accepted' review points to the PDF in question.

I hope this is clear enough, feel free to ask questions to clarify - perhaps I'm just missing something obvious, but perhaps applying changes to an already existing PDF is not possible?

-d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, and long, no. They can't. Gutted.